# Generating function of Meixner polynomial

Tags: orthogonal-polynomials

how can I prove that
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty{\frac{m_n\left(x;b,c\right)}{n!}t^n}=\left(1-t\right)^{-x-b}\left(1-\frac{t}{c}\right)^x$$

I tried using
$$m_n\left(x;b,c\right)=\sum_{k=0}^{n}{\frac{n!}{(n-k)!\cdot k!}\left(x+b\right)_{n-k}\left(x-k+1\right)_{k}\left(-c\right)^{-k}}$$

this has created more confusing expression.
Please, suggest a way to do this.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplifying we obtain

$$m_n(x; b, c) =
n! \sum_{k=0}^n {x+b+n-k-1\choose n-k}
(-1)^k {x\choose k} c^{-k}
\\ = n! \sum_{k=0}^n [t^{n-k}] \frac{1}{(1-t)^{x+b}}
[t^k] \left(1-\frac{t}{c}\right)^x
\\ = n! [t^n] \frac{1}{(1-t)^{x+b}}
\left(1-\frac{t}{c}\right)^x.$$

This is the claim.